# Outputting MySQL processes in bash script

Tags: mysql, bash, import

Looking for help from the bash experts here.

What I am trying to do is probably incredibly simple, but I cannot find anything in google that is clearly explaining what to do. There is a lot of other stuff in the script but this is the block I need help on:

```
 # import the extracted sql into mysql
   for sql_file in $(find -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*$1*.sql" | sort); do
       echo "Importing: $sql_file"

       if mysql -u [USER] -p[PASSWORD] -h [HOST] $db < $sql_file
       then
           echo "Database $sql_file imported successfully. $db has been updated"
       else
           echo "ERROR: Database importing $sql_file into $db"
       fi
   done
```

If you cannot tell, I am basically trying to import multiple db.sql files into a given destination within a loop. What I would like to do is add the output of the mysql command to display any MySql errors that may be generated at this step. This output would come directly after this line:

```
echo "ERROR: Database importing $sql_file into $db"
```

If the import failed at this step, I would like it to output something like this, but not exit the script:

```
 MySQL Import Failed: [Output what mysql would output to command line right here.]
```

This would inform the person performing the import, what exactly went wrong so they can tell the developers exactly what they encountered.

I dont know if this is too vague or not, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the `mysql` command outputs any error messages, they will already appear in the output of this script - just *before* you echo the `ERROR` line.

Answer (score 1):

How about generating individual log and error files as follows:

```
for sql_file in $(find -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*$1*.sql" | sort); do
    echo "Importing: $sql_file"

    log=$sql_file.log
    err=$sql_file.err
    if mysql -u [USER] -p[PASSWORD] -h [HOST] $db < $sql_file > $log 2> $err
    then
        echo "Database $sql_file imported successfully. $db has been updated"
    else
        echo "ERROR: Database importing $sql_file into $db"
        echo "<<<<<" 
        cat $err
        echo ">>>>>"
    fi
done
```

This way you keep track of the processing of each script. For your original question it would suffice to just generate the error file. You can even delete it after the `cat` if you want.